# Dimension mismatch, while adding columns to existing Matlab matrix

Tags: matlab, matrix, multidimensional-array

I am looking for a tip to feed extra columns of `px matrix` with data, as my code ends up with `Error: Subscripted assignment dimension mismatch` from `z=2`. ps: While breaking the code it only works fine for `z=1`. I've also tried 
  `px(:,z:ind)=getsqldata(data{z,3})` as a way around but without success.

```
 ind=20;
 T=250; % time period
 z=1;  %initialization
 for i=z:ind
 while (data{z,6}~='C' ||data{i,6}~='OT')
       px(:,z)=getsqldata(data{z,3}); 
    if px(1,1)=='No Data'
       error('test');
    end
    ret(:,z) = -price2ret(px(:,z)); 
   ret=ret(1:T,1);
   z=z+1;
   end 
  end
```

Best,

ps: **getsqldata()** is my user-defined function, retrieving data from database. I can confirm that there is nothing wrong with it, as I've used it for a while.

Comment: You create `px` having only 1 column in the first iteration in the loop. The second tries to store data in column 2, but that does not exist. You need to initialise `px` as having `ind` columns, and the number of rows as coming from `getsqldata`

Comment: Though this is bad practice, try doing: `px = [px getsqldata(data{z,3})];`  This will **concatenate** columns in your matrix, but I would highly recommend you preallocate before hand like what Adriaan suggested.

Comment: thanks Adriaan , useful tip: the initialization. My little concern is that your suggestion implicitly forces me to hard-code the dimension of `px`, in particular the rows (`T`) from my query within `getsqldata()`. Unless I create a 2nd version of  `getsqldata_2()`, and finally manage 2 versions throughout the rest of the codes.

Comment: @rayryeng: as expected: `Undefined function or variable px`, using the advocated concatenation. nice try, anyway.

Comment: @owner Obviously you have to initialize `px` or it won't exist to append the new data. Try `px = [];` before the loop.

Comment: Your code didn't define this.... I thought it was already defined given your description.  At the top, write `px = [];`  BTW, it'd help if you gave us a semi-working piece of code so we don't suggest things needlessly.

Comment: @rayryeng: `px=[]` had not actually defined, and i've just done it resulting `Error using horzcat
Dimensions of matrices being concatenated are not consistent.` Similarly to Adriaan your concatenation solution might work only if the data queried got ex-ante same rows. My code only ensures this condition with `ret`; Sounds like no matter what..., I have to "hard-code".

Comment: @owner that means that each call to `getsqldata` returns a different number of rows each time.  No concatenation or preallocation in the world will save you.  Consider using cell arrays.

Comment: @rayryeng: you've got it as there is not guarantee that the arguments of `getsqldata()` got same rows (considering bank holidays in different locations, etc) unless i modify the query by setting rows=xxxx. Cheers.

Comment: @owner no problem.  In that case, do `px = {};` for a cell array and see what that gets you.  You can then access each "column" by `px{i}` where `i` is the ith column you want.

Comment: @rayryeng: Cheers. i will. then to carry matrix calculations one will have to resort to `cell2mat` each time (could be tedious). will compare the quickest solution between the latter one and also by creating `getsqldata_2()` in which i will set the number of rows.

Comment: @owner For sure.  That may be your best option.  You'll have to enforce that the `getsqldata` function returns a set number of rows.